# Getting code 400 (Bad request) when sending post request with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ajax, rest, jax-rs

I'm building an app which uses AngularJS on the client side and java on the server side. I'm trying to do a login, but when I send the data (`username` and `password`) via `POST` request using AngularJS, I keep getting this two errors:

```
POST http://localhost:8008/WebProjekat/rest/auth/login 400 (Bad Request)
```

and

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@542ca5bc; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: MyResponsePackage.User[\"username\"])","status":400,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/WebProjekat/rest/auth/login","data":{"username":{"ng339":8},"password":{"ng339":9}},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Authorization":"Basic","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Bad Request"}

Here is my angularjs code which does the post rquest:

```
factory.Login = function(username, password, callback){
    $http.post('/WebProjekat/rest/auth/login', {username: username, 
    password: password})
    .then(function(response){
       callback(response);
   })
}
```

Here is my java code which checks if the credentials are valid

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MyResponse login(User u) {
    String username = u.getUsername();
    String password = u.getPassword();
    MyResponse response = null;
    if(password.equals("test") && username.equals("test")) {
        response = new MyResponse(true, "Succes!");
    }else {
        response = new MyResponse(false, "Error");
    }
    return response;
}
```

And here is my User class

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I apologize if there is somewhere similar question with the answer. I've tried looking for it but could not resolve my problem. I hope the question is clear, if any further explanation is needed i'll provide it. If anyone could help me i'd be extremely greatful.

Comment: You need a no-arg constructor in the `User` class. Without it, it can't be created.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSamsotha for the answer, but that didn't solve the problem. The error stays the same. Any more ideas?

Comment: I don't know. It's a weird looking error. Not something I have ever seen before. And when/where are you seeing this message? Look in the developer console. Look in the network tab when you make the request. What is the request body that is being sent out? Can you post an image of that?

Comment: I found the mistake. When i was calling AuthService.Login from the controller instead of $scope.username and $scope.password i sent only username and password, and instead of really values it sent "ng-339:9" ( whatever that means).  It's rookie mistake, but i'm only starting with AngularJS. Thanks for the time you took to answer this question. Your insights were helpful.